# Automatically save a spreadsheet into an HTML file

Tags: html, openoffice-calc

I would like to know if there is a way to automate the process of saving a spreadsheet into an HTML file.

I have an OpenOffice spreadsheet that is located at a public file server inside my company´s LAN. A group of people work by editing and entering data into that spreadsheet, but others should only have read access. Since permissions policies can get a little bit complicated with OpenOffice, I thought it might be convenient for those who should only read the data to open the file in their web browsers by entering the route to the file or via a shortcut (specially since a lot of the read-only users are spreadsheet illiterates).

How can I achieve for this an HTML file to be updated every time the spreadsheet is saved by editing users, so read-only users can have the latest version?

Comment: the permissions should be set on the filesystem level, not in OpenOffice...

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, use a [document management system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_management_system) that will keep older versions of the file to prevent mistaken edits by multiple people.  Most DMS's provide some users with the ability to edit and others with the ability to read the document.

However, I once worked on a project where we used a large commercial DMS that was too complex for the read-only users.  So we also ran a web server that provided read-only access to the documents.

Running a web server such as [Apache HTTP Server](https://httpd.apache.org/), it is possible to do what you are asking even without a DMS.  Provide a web form for people to submit edits to the document.  When an edited document is submitted:

1. Save a copy of the old file.
2. Update the main version to the new file.
3. Run a command line job to [convert the document](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/) to HTML.

Then read only users can view the HTML file by browsing to the web server.

Without a DMS or a web server, the best that can be done is to set file system permissions, as @mb21 said.  That would certainly be easier to set up, and might be good enough depending on your needs.